# Using spatial data in IBM bluemix

Tags: java, bigdata, spatial-query, ibm-cloud

I have a set of data in a table which contains latitude and longitude as well. I need to query these data which has Lat,Long within 5 km in radius.

I have tried using IBM bluemix with BigSQL and DashDB. Please sugguest a possible solution.

Note: I can't use any RDBMS databases like MySQL/PostGre. Constrained to use BigData.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the Cloudant DBaaS service. It is built on top of CouchDB and is particularly good at handling geospatial data. Check out the following site for more info: https://cloudant.com/product/cloudant-features/geospatial/

Answer (score 0):

dashDB is the best solution in Bluemix for analysing spatial data. It have predefined spatial functions too.

You said you have tried dashDB.  Did you face any problems ?  Please let me know and i can help you in that.

Thanks,

Comment: Please dont leave a comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use dashDB for that.

It provides all the OGC standard conform SQL extensions. For your case you would take `ST_Buffer` function to define a circle geometry around a given point (use `ST_GeomFromText` to construct the geometry point from a given longitude and latitude). Then you would use `ST_Within` to find all rows where the geometry (I assume you just have points for now) is within the circle.

Something like the following predicate should work for you:

```
WHERE DB2GSE.ST_WITHIN( your_points_column, DB2GSE.ST_Buffer( 
    DB2GSE.ST_GeomFromText( 'POINT (<long float value>, <lat float value>)', 1005), 
    5000, 'METRE') = 1
```

Here is an example that should work with the dashDB sample data right away:

```
with target as (select db2gse.st_buffer(db2gse.st_geomfromtext('POINT
    (-80.6233232399 40.0725289742)',1005),10000,'METRE') as buffer
from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1) SELECT count(*) FROM SAMPLES.GEO_CUSTOMER C,
    TARGET T WHERE DB2GSE.ST_WITHIN(C.SHAPE,T.BUFFER) = 1
```

Relevant documentation links for:

- [ST_Within](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SS6NHC/com.ibm.db2.luw.spatial.topics.doc/doc/rsbp4158.html); and
- [ST_Buffer](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SS6NHC/com.ibm.db2.luw.spatial.topics.doc/doc/rsbp4038.html)

In response to a comment above is about Cloudant, here is one more goody: you can set up a dashDB warehouse for any given Cloudant db very easily in the Cloudant.com portal. The schema is discovered automatically and initial load as well as ongoing ETL is also automatically done.